# What morphing means?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I want to know what morphing means mathematically or how can i found out, in books or websites because i didnt find much about the subject only this:

[wiki article](https://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphing&ei=uHjnmzVF&lc=pt-BR&s=1&m=748&host=www.google.com.br&ts=1499986070&sig=ALNZjWnzIa-tXFs6bQe32foveRpaFIQgyA)

Thanks!!!

Comment: it's ill defined, there are multiple precise interpretations of this

Comment: Do you know any source material about it, because i only find this wikipedia website

Comment: For example: its a linear transformation its on algebraic topology, like where i found about it.

Comment: Example: take blender, a take one object and use the funtion morphe to transform in another object what is happening there

Comment: Sorry for any language mistake!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See these books:

- [Digital Image Warping](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0818689447) by Wolberg
- [Warping & Morphing of Graphical Objects](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1558604642) by Gomes et al.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!!